# Plain JS countdown with repeat and delay

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I keep running into several issues when creating a countdown script

1. it does not run smoothly
2. hard to make it repeat (closure)
3. hard to delay the start and to delay the repeat (closure)

Can someone please help me FIX this code which should work in my opinion but doesn't

the processing I need is

a. counter starts *delay* number of seconds after the page loads,
b. when counter reaches 0, the countdown RE-starts after *delay* number of seconds

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/RVBDQ/)

Issues:

1. when it starts, the counter seems to wait an additional second before counting down
2. it does not pause
3. the repeat starts after the counter has continued

.

```
// more accurate timer - https://gist.github.com/1185904
function interval(duration, fn){
  this.baseline = undefined

  this.run = function(){
    if(this.baseline === undefined){
      this.baseline = new Date().getTime()
    }
    fn()
    var end = new Date().getTime()
    this.baseline += duration

    var nextTick = duration - (end - this.baseline)
    if(nextTick<0){
      nextTick = 0
    }
    (function(i){
        i.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        i.run(end)
      }, nextTick)
    }(this))
  }

  this.stop = function(){
   clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }
}
window.onload=function() {
  var cnt1 = 10;
  var delay1 = 5;
  var timer1 = new interval(1000, function(){
    document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML=cnt1--
    if (cnt1 <= 0) { // trying to reset
      timer1.stop(); // does not work
      cnt1 = 10;
      setTimeout(function() { timer1.run()},delay1*1000)
    }
  })
  setTimeout(function() { timer1.run()},delay1*1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object exposing `start([delay])` and `stop()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/RVBDQ/3/

```
function interval(duration, fn, delay){
    this.timer = null;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.fn = fn;

    this.start(delay);
}
interval.prototype.start = function(delay){
    if (this.timer) {return;}
    var self=this;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){ self.run(); }, delay||0);
};
interval.prototype.run = function(called){
    var self = this,
        nextTick = called ? this.duration - (new Date - called) : 0;

    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        self.fn();
        self.run(new Date);
    }, nextTick<0 ? 0 : nextTick);
};
interval.prototype.stop = function(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = null;
};

window.onload = function() {
    var cnt1 = 10;
    var delay1 = 5;
    window.timer1 = new interval(1000, function(){
        document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML=cnt1;
        cnt1 = cnt1 === 1 ? 10 : cnt1-1;
    }, delay1*1000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks - can you please show me how to, in the onload, start it as now after delay number of seconds, and then when it stops RESTART it again after delay number of seconds - so 5 seconds after the page loads, the time starts and 5 seconds after it ends, it starts again.

Comment: PS: I see you use new Date without the () - would you like to explain the reason for that? Thanks

Comment: @mplungjan, just change the halting condition: http://jsfiddle.net/RVBDQ/4/ (note I also changed the order of two lines of code in the main body in this example). You could make this much more advanced as well. Like checking whether the function returns false and automatically stopping, etc.

Comment: @mplungjan, there's no real reason I do `new Date` without the brackets. JSLint doesn't like it when you don't use brackets, although the ECMAScript standard allows it (section 11.2 and 11.2.2 the first part). I don't do `.getTime()` because it is automatically converted to a number in this code in all cases. So leaving out `()` and `.getTime()` makes the code shorter. No real difference, it's just personal taste.

Comment: Thanks! Before I accept, are you not polluting the window object with your vars? Is the fact you make timer1 global the reason it works or is there a more elegant (puritanical) way of doing this?

Comment: @mplungjan, I made it global just so it would be easy to add the inline event handlers in the html (which is something I would never actually do. I.e. inline event handlers, or misused global variables like that). Obviously you can make them local to the onload function in which you can also set the event handlers, and then you don't need globals.

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten your code to produce the desired results. Your previous code was very inefficient. See my script comments for usage.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/RVBDQ/1/

```
/*
  @name  timer
  @param number startFrom     Starts counting down from this number
  @param number delay         Seconds to wait before repeating the counter
  @param number intervalDelay Milliseconds between countdown
  @param number runTimes      Optional; Limit of counting. The function stops when it has run <runTimes> times. Default 1 (=one countdown)
  @param Boolean noFirstRun   Optional; If false, the counter starts off immediately. Default false
*/

function timer(startFrom, delay, intervalDelay, runTimes, notFirstRun){
    if(typeof runTimes == "undefined") runTimes = 1;
    if(runTimes-- < 0) return;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var ctn = startFrom;
        var timer1 = window.setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = ctn--;
            if(ctn <= 0){
                clearInterval(timer1);
                timer(startFrom, delay, intervalDelay, runTimes, true);
            }

        }, intervalDelay);
    }, notFirstRun?delay*1000:0);
}
window.onload=function() {
    timer(10, 5, 1000, 2);
    //Runs two times, starts counting from 10 to 1, delays 5 seconds between counters.
}
```

Comment: You've slightly missed the point, the OP's code created a type. This is much less portable. You have neither `stop()` nor `run()` exposed to the user. Most importantly, the OP was trying to implement an interval without using `setInterval` to make it more accurate.

Comment: Yes that was the idea. Thanks