# java script countdown which repeats always with delay

Tags: javascript, timer

I am working on online auction bidding project which requires person to place bid before time runs out. so found answer on [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567079/plain-js-countdown-with-repeat-and-delay)

so i want to run that timer loop always.and when timer reaches 0 place bid button should be disabled and enabled when timer starts how can i achieve that.here is code i referenced from above link which runs only for two times.

```js
function timer(startFrom, delay, intervalDelay, runTimes, notFirstRun){
    if(typeof runTimes == "undefined") runTimes = 1;
    if(runTimes-- < 0) return;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var ctn = startFrom;
        var timer1 = window.setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = ctn--;
   document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = "You can Place BID!";
            if(ctn <= 0){
    gotit();
                clearInterval(timer1);
                timer(startFrom, delay, intervalDelay, runTimes, true);
            }

        }, intervalDelay);
    }, notFirstRun?delay*1000:0);
}
window.onload=function() {
    timer(10, 5, 1000, 2);
}    
function gotit()
{
document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = "Bidding closed!";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div>Biddind closes in <span id="out1"></span> seconds!</div>
 <div id="out2">You can Place BID </div>
 <form>
 <input type="text" name="amount"/>
 <input type="submit" id="btnct" value="Place Bid"/>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplit put document.getElementById("btnct").disabled = false/true in the right place and that's it;

```js
function timer(startFrom, delay, intervalDelay, runTimes, notFirstRun){
    if(typeof runTimes == "undefined") runTimes = 1;
    if(runTimes-- < 0) return;
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("btnct").disabled = false;
        var ctn = startFrom;
        var timer1 = window.setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = ctn--;
   document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = "You can Place BID!";
            if(ctn <= 0){
                document.getElementById("btnct").disabled = true;
    gotit();
                clearInterval(timer1);
                timer(startFrom, delay, intervalDelay, runTimes, true);
            }

        }, intervalDelay);
    }, notFirstRun?delay*1000:0);
}
window.onload=function() {
    timer(10, 5, 1000, 2);
}    
function gotit()
{
document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = "Bidding closed!";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div>Biddind closes in <span id="out1"></span> seconds!</div>
 <div id="out2">You can Place BID </div>
 <form>
 <input type="text" name="amount"/>
 <input type="submit" id="btnct" value="Place Bid"/>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it helped me a lot but the timer dosn't work for always what would be solution for that ,i want to runt it all time